# MVVM using Python's tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, tkinter, mvvm

My task is to change the architecture of a previously written application to **Model-View-ViewModel** and use the **Command** pattern. It is written in **Python 3.10.6** and uses the **tkinter** library for the GUI.

From previous research, I noticed that the core concept behind MVVM is binding: automated communication between the View and the bound properties of ViewModel. However, **tkinter does not have such a binding technology**, unlike pyqt.

Given that my project is huge, I do not wish to re-implement the interface in an MVVM-compatible language/ technology. It is enough for me to mock this binding. For a minimal reproducible example, I started off with [ArjanCode's MVC example](https://github.com/ArjanCodes/2022-gui/tree/main/mvc). I removed the database connection, and tried to convert it to MVVM. It currently looks as follows:

command.py:

```
from typing import Protocol


class Command(Protocol):
    def execute(self) -> None:
        ...
```

add_task_command.py:

```
from command import Command
# to avoid circular import error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5cjckVzY4g
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from view_model import ViewModel


class AddTaskCommand(Command):
    def __init__(self, view_model: 'ViewModel'):
        self.view_model = view_model

    def execute(self) -> None:
        print("Executing add task command")
        self.view_model.model.add_task(self.view_model.my_entry)
```

get_task_commands.py:

```
from command import Command
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from view_model import ViewModel


class GetTasksCommand(Command):
    def __init__(self, view_model: 'ViewModel'):
        self.view_model = view_model
        self.result = None

    def execute(self) -> None:
        self.result = self.view_model.model.get_tasks()
```

model.py:

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.tasks: list[str] = ["Ask StackOverflow", "Write Documentation", "Take a Nap"]

    def add_task(self, task: str) -> None:
        self.tasks.append(task)

    def delete_task(self, task: str) -> None:
        self.tasks.remove(task)

    def get_tasks(self) -> list[str]:
        return self.tasks
```

view.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from view_model import ViewModel


class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.view_model = ViewModel()
        self.title("To Do List")
        self.geometry("500x300")
        self.create_ui()
        self.update_task_list()

    def create_ui(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.task_list = tk.Listbox(
            self.frame,
            height=10
        )
        self.task_list.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)
        self.task_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_select_task)
        self.task_list.pack(fill=tk.X)

        self.my_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.view_model._my_entry)
        self.my_entry.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.my_entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_my_entry_return)

        self.del_task_button = tk.Button(
            self.frame,
            text="Delete",
            width=6,
            pady=5,
            state=tk.DISABLED
        )
        self.del_task_button.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_del_task_button_click)
        self.del_task_button.pack()

    def on_my_entry_return(self, event=None) -> None:
        self.view_model.my_entry = self.my_entry.get()
        self.update_task_list()
        self.my_entry.delete(0, "end")

    def on_del_task_button_click(self, event=None) -> None:
        self.view_model.delete_task()
        self.update_task_list()

    def on_select_task(self, event=None) -> None:
        self.del_task_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.view_model.selected_task = self.task_list.get(self.task_list.curselection())

    def on_focus_out(self, event=None) -> None:
        self.task_list.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        self.del_task_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def update_task_list(self) -> None:
        self.task_list.delete(0, tk.END)
        for item in self.view_model.get_tasks():
            self.task_list.insert(tk.END, item)
        self.del_task_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.task_list.yview(tk.END)
```

view_model.py:

```
import tkinter as tk

from model import Model
from add_task_command import AddTaskCommand
from delete_task_command import DeleteTaskCommand
from get_tasks_command import GetTasksCommand


class ViewModel:
    _selected_task: [tk.StringVar]
    _my_entry: tk.StringVar

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()

        self._selected_task = tk.StringVar()
        self._my_entry = tk.StringVar()

        # self._task_list = tk.StringVar(value=self.model.get_tasks)
        self.add_task_command = AddTaskCommand(self)
        self.delete_task_command = DeleteTaskCommand(self)
        self.get_tasks_command = GetTasksCommand(self)

    def delete_task(self, event=None) -> None:
        self.delete_task_command.execute()

    def get_tasks(self) -> [str]:
        self.get_tasks_command.execute()
        return self.get_tasks_command.result

    @property
    def selected_task(self) -> str:
        return self._selected_task.get()

    @selected_task.setter
    def selected_task(self, value: str):
        self._selected_task.set(value)

    @property
    def my_entry(self) -> str:
        return self._my_entry.get()

    @my_entry.setter
    def my_entry(self, value: str):
        self._my_entry.set(value)
        self.add_task_command.execute()
```

main.py:

```
from view import View


def main() -> None:
    view = View()
    view.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is my approach correct? Does it follow the MVVM pattern? Is there a better way of writing it? And last but not least, how would I mimic the binding for other widgets, like buttons and clickable labels? (for a slider it seems straight forward, since I can bind it with an IntVar).